# Copy one sheet to many others spreadsheets at the same folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have many spreadsheets inside a folder and today I have developed a new sheet (tab) inside one of these spreadsheets. I have a code to copy and paste one sheet to another spreadsheet, but for this there is another way without code.

My goal is:

- a way to copy one sheet (order number 13) to all other spreadsheets at the same folder.

This is my code for copying one-to-one:

```
function sendspreadsheet(){
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var aba = source.getSheets()[13];
var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https:sheetID');
aba.copyTo(destination);}
```

I have a great help from @Tanaike about similar issue at post: ["Array for Google Sheet celarcontet"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66448174/array-for-google-sheet-clearcontent/66449334?noredirect=1#comment117486323_66449334) and I have studied this code and Google Class Sheet, but something is not working.

Code I'm trying to copy one-to-multiple spreadsheets at the same folder:

```
     Function sendtomultiple(){
        var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var aba = source.getSheets()[13];
        var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById('1o6p-53Q1ntJAVIJt9w4k0UK___XXXXXX');
          var sheetDestino = destination.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
        while (sheetDestino.hasNext()) {
            SpreadsheetApp.open(sheetDestino.next()).getSheets().forEach(aba => {
              aba.copyTo(sheetDestino);          
            });
        };
       }
```

I guess this line into while instruction is the problem, I have tried other options, but all them return error message, kind this:

```
Exception: The parameters (DriveApp.FileIterator) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.copyTo.
```

Hope someone can help to fix this.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will fix this right now. Yes @Mario, one sheet to multiple spreadsheets at the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation / Issue:

Your goal is to copy a particular sheet (tab) into multiple spreadsheets within the same folder.

- The issue has do to with the fact that `sheetDestino.next()` is a [file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) object but [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) accepts a [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object.
- You can [get the id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getId()) of the file and then use [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)) to get the spreadsheet object which you can use to copy the sheet to.

**Bonus code:**

- I added an `if` condition to make sure the code does not try to copy the sheet to the origin spreadsheet file.
- I added a code to rename the copied sheet to the destination sheet to the original name. The default would be `copy of Sheet14..`.

### Solution:

```
function sendtomultiple(){
    const source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const source_id = source.getId();
    const aba = source.getSheets()[13];
    const destination = DriveApp.getFolderById('1o6p-53Q1ntJAVIJt9w4k0UK___XXXXXX');
    const sheetDestino = destination.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
    while (sheetDestino.hasNext()) {
          let target_file = sheetDestino.next();
          let target_id = target_file.getId();
          let target_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(target_id);
          if(target_id!=source_id){
             aba.copyTo(target_ss).setName(aba.getName());          
          } 
    };
}
```

Keep in mind that sheet `getSheets()[13]` is the 14th sheet in the spreadsheet file. If you want to get the 13th sheet you need to use `getSheets()[12]`.

Comment: it's working fine and the addition were great, specially that one for renaming the copied to the original name. I forgot that when you copy one sheet it's created with the name "copy of original name'". Thanks a lot.

Comment: @IvanSinigaglia glad it was helpful to you :)